Distortion in transformation from equirectangular panorama to perspective image
Given an equirectangular panorama (aspect ratio 2:1, resolution 4000x2000), the orientation of the camera, the desired image shape and a 2D FOV, I'm trying to convert it into a perspective image. Depending on the orientation vector, the perspective image will either look correct or be rotated incorrectly and distorted.

The orientations that look wrong are the ones that have an x- and a y-component. All the other orientations I've tested look correct. Do you have any idea what part of my code is causing this problem?
def calculate_R(orientation, up=cp.array([0, -1, 0])):

    orientation = orientation / cp.linalg.norm(orientation)

    if cp.allclose(orientation, up):
        return cp.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, -1, 0]])

    if cp.allclose(orientation, -up):
        return cp.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, 1, 0]])

    x = cp.cross(up, orientation)
    x = x / cp.linalg.norm(x)

    y = cp.cross(orientation, x)
    y = y / cp.linalg.norm(y)

    R = cp.array([x, y, orientation])

    return R

def rotate_xyz(R, x, y, z):

    xyz = cp.stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()))
    x, y, z = cp.matmul(R, xyz).reshape(3, *x.shape)
    
    return x, y, z

def transform_back(pano, orientation, image_shape, fov=[90, 90]):

    orientation = orientation / cp.linalg.norm(orientation)

    fov_x = cp.radians(fov[0])
    fov_y = cp.radians(fov[1]))

    x_max = cp.tan(fov_x / 2)
    y_max = cp.tan(fov_y / 2)

    x = cp.linspace(-x_max, x_max, num=image_shape[1], dtype=cp.float32)
    y = cp.linspace(-y_max, y_max, num=image_shape[0], dtype=cp.float32)
    x, y = cp.meshgrid(x, y)
    z = -cp.ones_like(x)

    R = calculate_R(orientation)

    x, y, z = rotate_xyz(R, x, y, z)
    xyz = cp.stack([x, y, z], axis=-1).reshape(-1, 3)

    lon = cp.arctan2(xyz[:, 0], xyz[:, 2])
    lat = cp.arcsin(xyz[:, 1] / cp.linalg.norm(xyz, axis=1))

    u = ((lon + cp.pi) / (2 * cp.pi)) * pano.shape[1]
    v = ((cp.pi / 2 - lat) / cp.pi) * pano.shape[0]

    u = u.reshape(image_shape[0], image_shape[1]).astype(cp.float32)
    v = v.reshape(image_shape[0], image_shape[1]).astype(cp.float32)

    image = cp.empty((image_shape[0], image_shape[1], pano.shape[2]), dtype=pano.dtype)
    for i in range(pano.shape[2]):
        image[:, :, i] = ndimage.map_coordinates(pano[:, :, i], cp.stack([v, u]), order=1, mode='wrap')

    return image


I'm still not 100% sure why, but I solved my problem by using the inverse of the rotation matrix and flipping the x-component of the orientation.
I added
orientation[0] *= -1

and replaced
R = calculate_R(orientation)

with
R = cp.linalg.inv(calculate_R(orientation))

